# Is it possible to modify a UK visa application or the visa itself to add an extra day?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens

My mother-in-law, who is from the Philippines, has applied for a six-month visa to the UK. We are flying to visit her and she will be returning with us. In our invitation letter, we specified a date in August until February 2023, which was a few days shorter than six months.

Now, upon looking at the tickets again, we have realized that if we fly from the Philippines one day earlier, it will save us around £800. Is it possible to change the start date on a visa?

She has only just made the application and we do not have the result yet. The company that processes the application in the Philippines is VFS, and they do not want us to contact them while the application is in progress.

Comment: What is the exact itinerary and class of service, how many people are travelling, and what constraints do you have, if any? I barely see a difference of 100€ on return MNL-LON flights departing in August. Maybe you can get better fares departing a day or two later as well? That would probably be simpler than changing the visa dates.

Comment: I assume you have allready written a request to those who accepted the visa application to pass this information (one day earlier) on, so that by the time a decision will be made they will know of the changed itinerary? Otherwise a decision will be maded based on the information you supplied them. The longer you wait, the less time exists to reach them before the applicaction is processed.

Comment: Thanks for your commnets. @jcaron It's only for my mother-in-law to come to UK. We (2 adults, 2 kids) are going to visit her and on the way back she is coming with us.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the company that process the application in the Philippines is VFS. But they don't want us to contact them whilst the application is underway. (That's why I asked both if someone has done it before the approval or after). But I'll ask my mother-in-law to call them again to ask. Thanks

Comment: Please add that information to your question.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @SERPRO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes

Long Answer: I did send a written request to the VFS, they never replied but when we got the passport back the Visa was with the dates I requested after the original application.